# Wix: Overwriting a file being installed by a merge module within same msi?

Tags: module, merge, windows-installer, overwrite

I'm given a situation in which a file needs to overwrite, installed by a merge module, packed with same msi, i.e. this overwritten process should happen within same msi installation.

I actually tried with  element but it didn't work.

I thought about adding Custom Action, but with two confusions:
When to launch this Custom Action?
If it removes the one comes with a merge module, Installer might try to restore it afterwards.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

A merge module becomes a part of the MSI during the merge process. So inside your MSI there is no distinction between MSI files and MSM files.

The files in your package are installed based on their sequence in [File table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So the only way to make a file overwrite a different file from the same package is to make sure it's sequence is higher.

Comment: Hi Cosmin,
Thanks for reply. Actually I tried this but using Orca. But that generates error that it can't find the file comes with merge module and installation rolled back.

BTW, how to do the sequence game using WIX?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest replacing the file in the `File` table, i.e. not to overwrite it but change the installed file. I guess you would need to add the updated file into your MSI, and then edit the `File` table: remove the reference to the file which comes from the merge module.

Comment: How do you make the sequence higher? Can it be done w/in the Wix xml?   How do you edit the File table to ensure that it's higher?

Comment: You can do it only by editing the MSI, so only with Orca or another MSI editor. Simply select the File table and modify the Sequence column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by removing the file (and the component) from the merge module using Orca. Then I added the new version of the file to my WiX project in the same way as all other files.